# Restore sharepoint 2010 web application on different domain

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010, backup

We made a backup of a web application through the central administration to move it to a different server on a different domain and it's a domain controller actually.

So we made a restore operation on the destination server from the central administration but never managed to succeed.

with errors like: Object failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory.SPException: The specified user or domain group was not found.

I tried every user account possible with no success. any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

Did you try with "New Configuration" option while restoring? I believe the problem is related to the users/groups added to the site and those users do not exist in new environment!

Also can you try restore using PowerShell with -Force switch parameter and see if that is successfull?

Comment: I tried the new config option, and I entered the server administrator account credentials but didn't work.

Comment: Also, did you actually evaluate different backup/restore methods available at your disposal? I was wondering if you could have chosen Site Collection Backup/Restore method if you are migrating to a farm which was created/configured from scratch independent of your source farm.